# Doctrine multiple 1 to 1 connections

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have task that would be quite simple using regular SQL query but the project is built using doctrine and I am looking for an optimal solution. Maybe someone could advise what would be a good way to approach this.

I have a quite complicated db structure but the simplified version of objects in question look like this:

```
| Category |      | Product     |      | ProductOption    |
------------      ---------------      --------------------
| id       |      | id          |      | id               |
| name     |      | category_id |      | product_id       |
------------      | name        |      | some_data        |
                  ---------------      --------------------
```

Product Option and Product have 1 to 1 connection. But options are created per category (I get 1 entity per category, but need to replicate that entity for every product and store that as 1 to 1 since at some point those options will need to be edited individually. Now there are many ways to do that (the dirty way) , but I would like some advice on how to do that in the most optimal way.

Comment: what i get is CategoryProductOption ($cpo), what i need to do is for each VehiclesInCategory as Vehicle { $po = new ProductOption(); $po->some_data = $cpo->some_data; $po->vehicle = Vehicle; persist($po);} flush().   I want a more efficient way of doing this as my actual entities have a lot more fields. (P.S. it is pseudo code so leave my syntax alone ;) )